# Can mypy generics express passing the return sequence type as an argument?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'd like to write the following generic Python code:

```python
from itertools import chain
from typing import Sequence, Hashable, List, Tuple, Type, TypeVar


SequenceT = TypeVar('SequenceT', bound=Sequence)
HashableT = TypeVar('HashableT', bound=Hashable)


def merge_and_sort_into(seq_type, *iterables):
    # type: (Type[SequenceT], *Iterable[HashableT]) -> SequenceT[HashableT]
    return seq_type(sorted(set(chain(*iterables))))


def merge_and_sort_into_list(*iterables):
    # type: (*Iterable[HashableT]) -> List[HashableT]
    return merge_and_sort_into(list, *iterables)


def merge_and_sort_into_tuple(*iterables):
    # type: (*Iterable[HashableT]) -> Tuple[HashableT]
    return merge_and_sort_into(tuple, *iterables)
```

The code is fine, but mypy doesn't like the return type of `merge_and_sort_into()` saying `error: Type variable "SequenceT" used with arguments`. How can I pass a Sequence type into a function and also use that type as the return type?  (note: I'm not capturing the fact that the value type for the sequence also needs to be comparable/sortable, but let's just ignore that).

Here is a version that mypy will accept, but it doesn't capture the constraint that type passed into `merge_and_sort_into()` is its return type, hence the casts.

```python
def merge_and_sort_into(seq_type, *iterables):
    # type: (Callable[[Iterable[HashableT]], Sequence[HashableT]], *Iterable[HashableT]) -> Sequence[HashableT]
    return seq_type(sorted(set(chain(*iterables))))


def merge_and_sort_into_list(*iterables):
    # type: (*Iterable[HashableT]) -> List[HashableT]
    return cast(List[HashableT], merge_and_sort_into(list, *iterables))


def merge_and_sort_into_tuple(*iterables):
    # type: (*Iterable[HashableT]) -> Tuple[HashableT]
    return cast(Tuple[HashableT], merge_and_sort_into(tuple, *iterables))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mypy does not support generic type variables because they would require the type system to support higher kinds, as discussed in [this comment](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4395#issuecomment-352920631).

Even if Mypy supported generic type variables, the type signature of the original function would be incorrect, because not all `Sequence`s can be constructed from an iterable. For example,

```
class EmptyList(Sequence[T]):
  def __init__(self): pass
  def __getitem__(self, item): raise IndexError
  def __len__(self): return 0

EmptyList([1, 2, 3]) # TypeError
```

The most straightforward solution for your specific case is probably to simply allow non-sequence return types, and use `Callable` instead of `Type`.

```
T, R = TypeVar('T'), TypeVar('R')

def chain_into(into: Callable[[Iterable[T]], R], *iters: Iterable[T]) -> R:
    return into(chain.from_iterable(iters))
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized after I wrote the question that the Sequence type didn't give any guarantees on its constructor. I had tried the Callable approach and got it to typecheck, but it doesn't capture the fact that the return type is a Sequence[T] and not just a Sequence.

Comment: It doesn't help, but Mypy issue [#2756](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2756) and the related issues (especially [#3151](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3151)) discuss what you're trying to do and why it doesn't work.